# Rails carrierwave upload directory per user basis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have been trying to use Carrierwave for image uploads which is working fine, I was just wondering how I could have an upload directory for each user i.e:-

> uploads/current_user.id/gallery.id/

I have two tables,

images

- id
- title
- desc
- gallery_id
- created_at
- updated_at

galleries

- id
- title
- desc
- user_id
- created_at
- updated_at

many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Since you've provided very little in the way of specifics about your setup, I will make assumptions with my answer.*

If you have some `Gallery` model which the uploader in question is bound to, the uploader has a `model` method that returns the `Gallery` instance. I will also assume your `Gallery` instance has an `owner` relation for some `User` record. All you need to do is add a `store_dir` method to your uploader to overload the default `CarrierWave::Uploader::Base` provides.

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.owner.id}/#{model.id}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Deefour, would i then need to add the user id to the images table to?

Comment: I really have no idea, my answer describes **a** scenario, not necessarily **your** scenario. I still have don't know what model your uploader is bound to.

Comment: My appologies DeeFour for my vagueness, I am extremely new to this. I have solved the problem like this:- my uploader was bound to the Image model so i added a relationship for the image to the user model this then allowed me to use the user id in the store_dir method.

Thanks again for your patience

Comment: It's not necessary to add a new column/relation just for this purpose. You can get the user id through the `Image` instance's `Gallery` owner through `model.gallery.user` *(depending on the names of your relations)*.

Comment: As for the vagueness, I suggest you read [the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on the subject. You'll get better, faster help from more people if you provide all relevant information and code. Abstracting your problem away from your actual code does not help you get the specific answer you might be looking for.